# An algebra/linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Suppose 8 real numbers $a,b,c,d$ and $x,y,z,w$ satisfy 
\begin{equation*}
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1,\quad ax+by+cz+dw=0.
\end{equation*}

Is it true that
\begin{equation*}
(ay-bx)(cw-dz)-(az-cx)(bw-dy)+(aw-dx)(bz-cy)=0?
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(ay-bx)(cw-dz)-(az-cx)(bw-dy)+(aw-dx)(bz-cy)=0$ regardless of the hypotheses because every product cancels. For instance, $aycw$ cancels with $awcy$.